# Difference between "daily" and "daily basis"

Tags: word-meaning, phrase-meaning, difference

> They are books that had at least one idea, but in most cases more,
>   that actually changed the trajectory of my life or *the way that I act
>   or think on **a daily basis***.

So, what is the meaning of the phrase *daily basis* and how it is different from the word *daily*?

Comment: the way I act or think in my daily life. I would not use it here at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**daily** refers to frequency, like **weekly** or **monthly**.

> Take this medicine twice daily, once in the morning and again at bedtime.

**on a daily basis** there refers to everyday life, to one's normal or usual behavior, activity, routine, or schedule, to the quotidien.

> Now that you're retired, what do you do on a daily basis? Do you have any new hobbies? Do you take walks? What's it like?

Comment: In particular, _daily_ is an adjective, so it modifies a noun ("a daily newspaper"), while _on a daily basis_ is an adverbial phrase, so it modifies a verb ("I run on a daily basis").

Comment: *On a daily basis* is employed quite widely as the equivalent of adverbial *daily*, particularly in bureaucratic contexts.

Comment: @MikeHarris *Daily* is freely deployed as an adverb, as in Tᴚoɯɐuo's first example.

Comment: @StoneyB: Agreed. I was explaining how it was used in the OP's sentence. I should add a "there" there.

Comment: Ahh, good point @StoneyB, not sure how I missed that.

Comment: _On a ... basis_ is often unnecessary verbiage.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference in meaning between the adverbs *daily*/*hourly*/*weekly*/*monthly*, &c, and the preposition phrases *on a daily/hourly/weekly/monthly basis* deployed as adverbials.

The PPs are superfluous and verbose, but they have virtually replaced the adverbs in most contexts. Present-Day English has become more and more uncomfortable with deploying the same word as both an adjective and an adverb, and the discomfort is exacerbated when the word has the *-ly* suffix, which today is 'productive' only in creating adverbs. There is consequently a strong tendency to restrict ambivalent *-ly* words to adjectival use and express the adverbial sense with a PP. This is true not only of these time expressions but also other *-ly* adjectives—*friendly*, for instance, is very rarely employed as an adverb today, that sense being expressed by *as a friend* or *in a friendly manner*.

Comment: I would say that *on a daily basis* in the OP refers to the "everyday" not to "every day".